# "Upload Pending" in Word resolved by another person opening same document

Tags: file-upload

I have observed this twice where a Microsoft 365 Word document was stuck with "Upload Pending".  A second person opening the same document causes the first person upload to complete and save.  Is this a known behaviour?  Can anyone explain what's going on?  It doesn't make sense to me that those things should be related.